# Google Analytics, how to show behavior flow for specific path?

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics, my website has 1000's of visits across a few hundred URLs.

I'm trying to see how users accessed specific paths and where they went to afterwards. Like in behavior flow where you can explore the different interactions, but I need to be able to search for the specific page as its taking me ages to look through all the interactions trying to find specific paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly:

1. use the Navigation Summary view in the All Pages report, which will show you the Previous and Next pages, with respect to the page you have in question, or
2. use Custom Reporting to mimic the Navigation Summary report, but you would need to do this in two reports because of the nature of the "Previous Page Path" dimension (and also the deprecation of the "Next Page Path" dimension). Note that the PPP and NPP dimensions are meant only for the Nagivation Summary report.

Comment: Can you please also guide how to locate Navigation Summary? I can see Behavior Flow under Behavior link. But I am not sure where exactly is Navigation Summary.