# Google Analytics Report for referring URL or next page

Tags: google-analytics

Sounds like a simple report, but can someone guide me on how to set up a report where it shows a specific URL and from what previous page or referring URL brought them to the specific URL?

For example, the specific URL could be www.test.com/c2campaign

I want to create a report of all the previous pages that brought people to the above URL.

One thing to note is that www.test.com/c2campaign is not tagged for Google Analytics as it's an external site but all the referring pages are tagged for Google Analytics being our intranet site.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics, how to show behavior flow for specific path?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92298/google-analytics-how-to-show-behavior-flow-for-specific-path)

Comment: If the current URL is external (w/o GA), then you won't be able to pull that data into your reports. What you might try to do is to set an event for that outbound click, and then in your event label, include the current URL from where that outbound link was clicked. This way you'll at least see where the user was (on your site) before they clicked away.